# Evaluating a definite integral involving $\log(1+x)$

Tags: calculus

Find 
$$\int_0^1\frac{x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx$$
I think it has not an anti-derivative 
because i tried it with different ways such as using the sub $$x=\tan{y}$$ to be 
$$\int\tan{y} \ln\left(1+\tan{y}\right)dx$$
so what is the procedure to solve it?